# Which is the best approch to add styles to SPA?

Tags: css, single-page-application, reactjs

I am using `insert-CSS` node module for adding styles to DOM, internally this adds the embedded approach.
so far my understanding is using external style sheets is best way to do it. But while using insert CSS, css added to the js bundle and dynamically css embedded to the . so this also looks as same using external CSS.. and css will be cached with js and there will be one file(js+css) we can avoid one http request for loading CSS ?

I feel this insert-css is better than traditional approach(external css) am i correct? please suggest me your thought on the same and add some docs to refer.

so my question is which is the best approach among using "insert-css npm" or "external css"

Comment: External CSS is best option to use in SPA
An external style sheet has many advantages. Keeping the styles separate from your HTML content:
-Helps avoid duplication.
-Makes maintenance easier.
-Allows you to make a site-wide change in one place.

Comment: Thanks @shanidkv: I am with you and that's the traditional thoughts.
but this approach eliminates one css file http request right? 
for dev, we need to think about maintenance but in prod we need to think about performance. so do you have any idea/thought on this aspects?

Comment: Find the below link. Hope you can get all answers of your questions https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: @Manivannan did you find what is best solution for this question today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find useful info on this question and sharing my experience.

My personal recommendation is not to use "insert-css" modules for the simple projects like dealing with forms and minimal amount of components.

"insert-css" - as mentioned above, "insert-css" add the embedded styles, in the network, its passed as base64 format. Though it's less weight in the network, browser needs to convert the base64 format to css and adds the embedded css, this conversion process will happen allays in js side, I guess which will cause the performance issues